# Mikrotik: HowTo pre-define static leases in DCHP-server

Tags: dhcp-server, mikrotik

I would like to replace my current router by a Mikrotik (v6.48.3). In order not to mess up my network, I would like to pre-set the IP addresses the DHCP clients will get from the server. I do not find such an example, does anybody know how to do it? I have a list of IPs and MACs in a file, so I would appreciate CLI commands, I do not like clicking the mouse button so much ;-)

THX for your answers!
Christof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the lease sub-menu of the Mikrotik [dhcp-server lease configuration](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/DHCP_Server#Leases), e.g.:

```
/ip dhcp-server lease add address=192.168.0.23 mac-address=b6:c2:55:41:bb:14 ...
```

Comment: thx for the support!